# Order by with union showing error incorrect syntax with union

Tags: sql

```
select * 
from student_details
where student_rollnumber  in(644,1,2)
order by student_rollnumber 

union

select * 
from student_details
where student_rollnumber not in(644,1,2) ;
```

Comment: The ORDER BY should be at the end.

Comment: Hi...showing error at under union kayword. incorrect syntex near union

Comment: You want to select all records that `student_rollnumber in (644,1,2)` and that are `student_rollnumber not in (644,1,2)` What is the sense? Why do you not use `select * from student_details where student_rollnumber is not null`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? From the look of your query, you seem to want to select all records.

Comment: actually department_id column has data 100,30,100,45,46 - m expecting result in that column 100,100,30,45, 46.. means i just want sort decs in(100,30)

Comment: and Remaining data of that column should be same just want to sort those values those are in  IN operator

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ORDER BY` with `UNION` it should be at the end.

```
select * 
from student_details 
where student_rollnumber in(644,1,2) 
union 
select * 
from student_details 
where student_rollnumber not in(644,1,2) 
order by student_rollnumber;
```

If `student_rollnumber` is `NOT NULL` then your query is the same as:

```
select DISTINCT * 
from student_details 
order by student_rollnumber;
```

Comment: If student_rollnumber contains NULL, the queries are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want those three students first, then use `order by` with `case`, not `union`:

```
select sd.*
from student_details sd
order by (case when sd.student_rollnumber in (644,1,2) then 1 else 2 end),
         sd.student_rollnumber ;
```

There are several reasons why your approach is bad:

- A SQL result set is unordered unless the entire query ends with an `order by`.
- `UNION` is not efficient, because it has the overhead of removing duplicates.
- Even a `UNION ALL` is not always guaranteed to return the first subquery values first.

Comment: The other way round 0 then 1